# Do we need to consider a duplicate report in openFDA adverse event database? (like patient and doctor both submitted reports)

Tags: api, openfda

I am trying to search data with the drug name Hydroxychloroquine from the URL here from OpenFDA api

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.medicinalproduct:%22hydroxychloroquine%22+AND+receivedate:%5B20200101+TO+20200513%5D&limit=99 [Edited]

There are 2918 relative results, will some results repeat? For example, if a patient and doctor both submitted their own reports independently. Or if multiple doctors were treating the same patient.

Thanks!

Comment: As a general rule (speaking as a data analyst/programmer), it is always important to perform some data profiling to ensure that you understand this type of potential issue. Unfortunately I don't have a specific answer with regard to openFDA data

Comment: The query you posted actually produces only 35 total hits.